# Can't create 1 pixel brush in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, pixel

This has been driving me mad for the past 2 hours. I am stuck in a course where I need to create a 1 pixel brush. Every time I define a brush preset, it doesn't work as expected. Anti aliasing is turned off in most options. I then use the magic wand (I tried the square marquee select as well, doesn't work). Then to Edit -> Define Brush Preset. The Brush says 1 pixel but it doesn't look like a square but rather a square with an arch on the bottom right. It worked fine earlier, a square 1 pixel brush, suddenly it does not. I have reset Photoshop to it's defaults and also Preferences -> General -> Nearest Neighbor.

[image]
1 pixel square using the pencil at 1px

[image]

Another student had the same problem but somehow resolved it themselves:

> Blockquote
> Hi thanks for the reply! so i tried other brushes and they work. the pencil tool even with another 1 pix brush does 4 pixels and they are about 50 percent opacity. i will delete the brushes i made and try again.

Thank you for taking the time to read my problem, any help is deeply appreciated. Apologies for being a noob :(

EDIT

The instructor did it without any problems
[image]

The reason to use the brush is I need to create an 8px horizontally and vertically brush.

EDIT 2
[image]
That is the result I get when defining a brush preset of 8 pixels vertically (on the left is the pencil tool, on the right is the brush preset)

Comment: Why can’t you use the Pencil tool? Brushes only could be 100% opaque in specific blend modes (dissolve)

Comment: I need to create a 8px brush horizontally and vertically

Comment: So what’s the problem? Create a 8x8 brush and use this tip for Pencil tool

Comment: That "instructor" image shows the **Pencil Tool** being used.

Comment: @Scott see Edit 2, that's using the brush tool

Comment: Perhaps.. but the brush was *created with the Pencil Tool*. Maybe you simply need to pay closer attention to instructions? Or watch what the instructor is *actually* doing more closely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... use the **Pencil Tool** (Under the Brush Tool) for 1 pixel.

Brushes assume some smoothing is desired. The Pencil Tool won't.

Unless there's some reason I can't fathom, I don't know why 
anyone would attempt to define a 1px *brush*.

Comment: I need to create a 8px brush horizontally and vertically

Comment: @Deodorant then why are you defining a **1px** brush? Use the Pencil Tool to paint your 8px, then define a brush. And based upon that new image, your instructor IS using the **Pencil Tool**.

Comment: The 8px brush behaves like the 1px brush, it has anti aliasing or feathering around it

Comment: @Deodorant Create a square tip and use it for Pencil, not Brush tool

Comment: @Scott sigh oh my goodness. that is correct. I feel like kicking my self in the head. Thank you everybody for your help and apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: Glad you go it sorted, @Deodorant 

Comment: Pencil tool in 2022 doesn't have accurate sizes - it has been OK at times in the past, but currently, Photoshop's pencil tool gives the following pixel dimension from size 1 to 5 : 3x3, 2x3, 4x4, 4x4, 6x6 - just terrible for pixel work. Actually worse than terrible, unusable.